# In what sense does God mock or scoff at the wicked?

Tags: psalms

> He who sits in the heavens laughs, the Lord scoffs at them (Psalm 2:4, NASB)

In what sense does God mock or scoff at the wicked?

Answer (score 3):

Consider one of the sayings I grew up with:

> "He who laughs last, laughs best!"

More on that later.

Theologians speak of anthropomorphisms, and rightly they should.  God the Father does not have body parts, for one thing; He can, however, see and hear.

> "He who planted the ear, does He not hear?  He who formed the eye, does He not see?" (Psalm 94:8,9).

In other words, human body parts are simply metaphors for things that God can do to an infinite degree.  God not only sees, but He, unlike us, is omniscient and omnipresent.  Nothing escapes His notice.  Nothing.

Remember Sarah's handmaid Hagar, whom Abraham impregnated--with his wife's permission?  Fleeing from her home and her harsh mistress, Hagar wandered in the desert, despairing of life itself (Genesis 16).  Then the angel of the LORD appeared to her, telling her to return to her mistress and put herself under Sarah's authority (v.9).  Moreover, the angel told her that the descendants of her first-born son, Ishmael (meaning "God hears"), would one day be too many to count.  Overwhelmed with gratitude, Hagar

> "called the name of the LORD who spoke to her, 'You are a God who sees' [or in Hebrew, *El El Roi*]" (v.13).

Thereafter, the well where the LORD "found" Hagar was named *Beer Lahai Roi* (בְּאֵר לַחַי רֹאִי, *bÿ’er lakhay ro’i*), which means “The well of the Living One who sees me.”

God, then, can both see and hear.  Moreover, God, like us, has volition, or a will; and emotions, or affect, both positive and negative; for example, love, hate, indignation, compassion, anger/wrath, sympathy, and so much more.

The lesson in all this is, simply, if we humans are created in the image of God, then God's endowments to us are a reflection of God's endowments, whether they are intellectual, volitional, or emotional in nature.

Going back to "he who laughs last."  If God, like us, has humor (British humour) as an aspect of His being, then does it not stand to reason He is also able to laugh and to scoff?  God's humor, of course, is untainted by sin and imperfection as ours is. We, for example, laugh inappropriately or even wickedly because of our fallen nature.  God, on the other hand, laughs and scoffs at those who take their stand against Him and plot together against Him and His Anointed One, as if they had the ability to break free of His restraints, much as Satan did when his heart was filled with pride.

To break free of God, however, is an impossibility, at least in the end.  Why?  Because a day of reckoning is coming, and all those who oppose God in this life will, in the end, experience the wrath of God in its fullness.

*That* is what God finds so risible when He considers the machinations and evil intentions of those who take their stand against Him and His unalterable decrees (Psalm 2:7).  Their doom is sure; His victory is assured.  Just as Goliath of old disdained the young shepherd boy who had come out to meet him with a mere sling, so too will God one day say in effect to His enemies:  "Is that the best you've got?"

Then He who is called "the LORD of hosts and the LORD of the armies of heaven" will laugh.  He will have the last laugh, and His laugh will be best, for His enemies who once desired to exalt themselves over the God Most High (Heb., *El Elyon*) will be, as it were, mere footstools for His feet.  How fitting!

Comment: Yes that is right, the sense is perfect, thank you my friend, it warms the heart to hear such things. Truly God is Infinite and declares His splendor before our very eyes..In creation and in His word we find truth and only truth and every year brings more gold tested in the fire. 
54 “Sing, O barren,
You who have not borne!
Break forth into singing, and cry aloud,
You who have not labored with child!
For more are the children of the desolate
Than the children of the married woman,” says the Lord.
2 “Enlarge the place of your tent,
And let them stretch out the curtains of your dwellings;

Comment: @JohnUnsworth:  Thank you for the encouragement.  God bless you.

Comment: @Niobius:  Thank you for the compliment; I appreciate it!  God bless you.